# CSS dropdown 'hit box'

Tags: html, css

I don't really know how else to explain my problem other than asking how to increase the size of my dropdown 'hit box'

What I mean is that when my dropdown menu appears, I have to hover my mouse quite far to the left of the buttons otherwise the dropdown menu disappears, instead of just hovering over the hamburger icon and moving my mouse straight downwards. It only seems to happen when I am in full screen (2560x1440) otherwise it is fine. So you won't really be able to replicate unless you have the same size screen.

Also just another quick question, how come `Example Title` is displayed as

```
Example
Title
```

```css
/* Nav Bar Styling */

div.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
#title {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
span.dropbutton {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 2%
}
#lines:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* Dropdown Styling */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 50px 16px;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #343434;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="nav">
  <p id="title">Example Title</p>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span class="dropbutton">☰</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this resolution (mac 27").
If i understand, the problem is position fixed of `span class="dropbutton"` with left 2%.

In fullscreen is completely outside of `div class="dropdown"` while in small resolution the span ovelapped the div.

Comment: I changed it to `left: 20px;` and now works fine thanks. any idea of the `Example Title` issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
.dropdown:hover {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

About the title issue, there is a conflict with right: 50% and left: 50%.
Delete right: 50%, keep left: 50% and add to #title

```
transform: translateX(-50%)
```

Comment: I wondered about that just after I posted. Your solution fixed this issue, thanks

Comment: I edited my answer also for the other problem. I hope it is helpful too.